# Is it safe for an application using .NET 4.0 if the framework is replaced with .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I'm using Windows 7 and VisualStudio 2010. The application was developing is using the .net framework 4.0. Is it safe if I replace it with .NET 4.5? Will it break the app?

Will it matter if I'm developing using the framework 4.5 (without using its new features), and my teammates are using 4.0 and our production and staging are also using the 4.0?

Need to advise.

Comment: In the project I'm currently involved in there were some complications regarding Unit and Integration Tests. Some assemblies that are referenced by specific versions will obviously cause issues.

Comment: Any reason why you want to do that when the whole team is using .NET 4.0?

Comment: This seemed interesting *using the 4.5 framework(without using its new features)* why would you need to do so ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta I have an application at home running on 4.5 and I want to run it here in work place which is still 4.0. That is why i plan to install 4.5 but not sure if our current work apps will break upon installing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does .net 4.5 work side by side with .net 4.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745600/does-net-4-5-work-side-by-side-with-net-4-0)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to make sure you don't break anything when moving from 4.0 to 4.5 is test, test, and test.

From my experience, I have never found any problem when my team move a silverlight and wcf project from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the list of [changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) from .Net 4.0 to 4.5 and this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/09/26/compatibility-of-net-framework-4-5.aspx) for information about compatibility between 4.0 and 4.5.

As long as your project targets the 4.0 runtime you'll probably be OK, I've only experienced one hiccup and that was back in beta (dealing with compiled Regex assemblies). Also, I wouldn't expect the performance characteristics to be consistent between the devs running 4.0 and those running 4.5.