# .NET Framework installation on AWS server (requirement & possibility)

Tags: iis, .net-framework-version

I had deployed some web application on amazon server using .net framework 4.0.
Now i want to change .net framework to 4.5 in my new application.
If i install .net framework 4.5 Will it **Affect(harm) to my other application**??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does .net 4.5 work side by side with .net 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745600/does-net-4-5-work-side-by-side-with-net-4-0)

Comment: Microsoft has a guide, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/ As it is called a migration, you should expect impact/harm.